# select last array without knowing the total number of item

Tags: javascript

```
object = [
{"id":1,"name":"Joe"}
{"id":2,"name":"Joe1"}
{"id":3,"name":"Joe2"}
{"id":4,"name":"Joe3"}
]
```

I want to select {"id":4,"name":"Joe3} but I can't do like object[3] so it there any way to retrieve the last object of an array??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the total length of an array by using `length`.

```
array[array.length-1]
```